# group a query's values together based on its id

Tags: php, mysql, sql, mysqli

I have data coming from the database , i am using  JOIN(s) to select data from different tables,I need to be able to group the data together based on the specific id of the user in relation to the specific course, as an email needs to be sent based on the selection and within this selection(using a radio button) it will allow admin to be able to email all the users assigned to that specific category selected

i am currently getting duplicated data, like the users details will show on each category instead of being in one single category to pass into the array to email. I only need to select one radio button per category/course but now i am getting multiple radio buttons.

here is my query:

```
$query="SELECT * FROM course_student
    JOIN course ON course.course_id=course_student.course_id
    JOIN student ON student.student_id=course_student.student_id  
    WHERE course.course_id=course_student.course_id
    ORDER BY course.course_id";
```

this is my loop to select data -- it's creating duplicate names for the entries where i just want one name with all of the data that is supposed to be in it

```
$result=mysqli_query($connection,$query);
confirmation($connection);

while($course_email_students = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
    $course_email = $course_email_students['student_email'];
    $course_name = $course_email_students['course_name'] ."<br/>";
```

here is my html:

```
<input type="radio" name="course_mail[]" value="<?php echo $course_email ;?>">
<?php echo $course_name ?>


<?php } ?>
```

here is more code
html

```
<form action ="#" method="POST">

<P> <label for="">Send to specific student courses</label>


</p>




<?php  // email specific students


$query = "SELECT student.student_email, course.course_name, course.course_id
FROM course_student
JOIN student ON student.student_id=course_student.student_id  
JOIN course ON course.course_id=course_student.course_id
GROUP BY student.student_email, course.course_id
ORDER BY course.course_id";
$result=mysqli_query($connection,$query);
confirm_query($connection);
 while($course_email_students=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
  $course_student_email=$course_email_students['student_email'];
  $course_student_email_name=$course_email_students['course_name'] ."<br/>";


var_dump($course_email_students['student_email']);


?>  

<input type="radio" name="course_email[]" value="<?php echo $course_student_email ;?>">
<?php echo $course_student_email_name ?>
<P>  <label for="">Message</label>
    <p><textarea rows="10" cols="20" name="message"></textarea></p>

</p>

<input type="submit" name="submit" value="send">
```

here is the php for testing to see what comes through

```
    if(isset($_POST['submit'])){

// do validation


if(isset($_POST['course_email'])){

var_dump($_POST['course_email']);



}




}
```

Comment: @ialarmedalien i have taken a look at it but i am new to sql/php coulr you provide me an example?

Comment: There are some useful tutorials on [PHP/MySQL at TizTag](http://www.tizag.com/mysqlTutorial/mysqlgroupby.php).

Comment: @ialarmedalien i just tried using GROUP BY and it doe not return all the values  only 1 value when i have two based on/within the specific catergory/course

Comment: @ialarmedalien thanks but thats not the problem , problem is i need to the data to be grouped, as i need to send an email based on which users are in the group. I need to get all info as there are 3 tables.

Comment: For future questions, post the results you are currently getting, the results you expect to get, and the code that is producing the relevant results. You should read [the SO guide on how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Also, not all programmers are male.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the PHP you've posted, it appears that you are just using data from two, possibly three columns in your query. If so, it is much more efficient to select the specific columns you're interested in in the SQL. There's also a redundancy in the query where you're using the same condition for a `WHERE` as you have in a `JOIN`:

```
$query="SELECT student.student_email, course.course_name, course.course_id FROM course_student
    JOIN student ON student.student_id=course_student.student_id  
    JOIN course ON course.course_id=course_student.course_id     <-- !!!
             WHERE course.course_id=course_student.course_id     <-- !!!
    ORDER BY course.course_id";
```

There are two ways of selecting unique combinations of results with this select query; you can use [`DISTINCT`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/selecting-columns.html) or [`GROUP BY`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/group-by-functions.html).

DISTINCT:

```
$query = "SELECT DISTINCT student.student_email, course.course_name, course.course_id
    FROM course_student
    JOIN student ON student.student_id=course_student.student_id  
    JOIN course ON course.course_id=course_student.course_id
    ORDER BY course.course_name";
```

GROUP BY:

```
$query = "SELECT student.student_email, course.course_name, course.course_id, student.student_id
    FROM course_student
    JOIN student ON student.student_id=course_student.student_id  
    JOIN course ON course.course_id=course_student.course_id
    GROUP BY student.student_email, course.course_name
    ORDER BY course.course_name";
```

Now for the PHP code:

```
$c_name = '';  # course name
$c_id = '';    # course ID
$students = array();
while($aa = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result){

    if ($aa['course_name'] !== $c_name) {
        # the course name has changed. print out the course and student data
        make_radios($c_name, $c_id, $students);

        # set c_name to the new course name
        $c_name = $aa['course.course_name'];
        $c_id = $aa['course.course_id'];
        # set the students to the new student
        $students = array( $aa['student.student_email'] );
    }
    else {
        # add this student to the list of students
        $students[] = $aa['student.student_email'];
    }
}
# print out the last set of data
make_radios( $c_name, $c_id, $students );


function make_radios( $course_name, $course_id, $email_arr ) {

    $html = '<input type="radio" id="email' 
        . $course_id . '" name="course_email[]" value="'
        . implode(',', $email_arr) . '"> <label for="email' 
        . $course_id . '">$course_name</label>';
    # I don't know if you want to list all the email addresses or not... in case you do:
    $html .= "<ul>";
    foreach ($email_arr as $e) {
        $html .= "<li>$e</li>\n";
    }
    $html .= "</ul>";

    # append the message box
    $html .= '<label for="message' . $course_id . '">Message</label>'
        . '<textarea id="message' . $course_id . '" rows="10" cols="20" name="message">'
        . "</textarea>\n";

    echo $html; # or you could return $html
}
```

I would not recommend that you have the email addresses on the form--I'd use the student IDs and the students' names instead, and then have your script pull the appropriate email addresses from the database--but it's up to you, obviously.

Please read through the code and check you understand what it's doing. I'm happy to answer any questions.

Comment: thanks alot man . but i still get duplicate data , i need those emails to belong to a specific course as the student is registered only for that course.So Course A should contain all the students that belong to CourseA ect.  here is a pic             http://tinypic.com/r/kbxi78/8

Comment: i am oly debugging at the moment , i have not done email script as yet , all i am doing is checking to see/and get those values into the array.All i need is to have one radio button per course name and within that course the specific students who are registered for that course, so i can email them based on which courses they took.

Comment: i added all the code i have so far, its not much as problem right now lies with the duplicate radio buttons

Comment: this is the duplication i am getting http://tinypic.com/view.php?pic=kbxi78&s=8#.VCsDU2SSzgI       the radio buttons, displaying for each email instead of within each course.like CourseC displays twice when it should display once and contain both the different students emails the same goes for CourseD

Answer (score 0):

*Group* and *Order* are words that have meaning both in English and in SQL jargon. You've said you want your values *grouped*. I think you mean, in SQL terms, you want them *ordered*, in such a way that each course's student emails are together.

There are some problems with your query.

First, Pro tip: Avoid using `SELECT *` in software. (It's OK when you're troubleshooting databases, but it's wasteful and confusing in software, especially when you're `JOIN`ing more than one table.)

Second, you have this condition repeated in both your `JOIN...ON` and your `WHERE` clause. That's redundant.

```
course.course_id = course_student.course_id
```

Leave it in your `ON` clause and out of your `WHERE` clause.

Third, your result set's order is underdetermined. This may not matter, but you are ordering only by course id. If you care whether your result set is ordered by student email, then mention it in the `ORDER BY` clause.

Fourth, you do have three tables. But one of them, `course_student`, appears to be a classic join table allowing there to be a many-to-many relationship between courses and students. So it seems likely you only have two tables with actual application data items in them.

Finally, from the code in your question it looks like you want

```
course_id
course_name
student_email
```

in your result set generated by your `SELECT` query. Your question's narrative mentions category, but because you've used `SELECT *` we can't tell what you mean by that.

To get the unique values of those three fields in your result set, use this query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
       course.course_id,
       course.course_name,
       student.student_email
  FROM course_student
  JOIN course  ON course.course_id=course_student.course_id
  JOIN student ON student.student_id=course_student.student_id  
 ORDER BY course.course_id, student.student_email
```

The `DISTINCT` qualifier eliminates duplicates.

From your comment, it's still hard to tell what you want. But it seems that you want to try this:

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT course.course_name),
       student.student_email
  FROM course_student
  JOIN course  ON course.course_id=course_student.course_id
  JOIN student ON student.student_id=course_student.student_id  
 GROUP BY student.student_email
 ORDER BY student.student_email
```

Or maybe you want this.

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT student.student_email),
       course.course_name
  FROM course_student
  JOIN course  ON course.course_id=course_student.course_id
  JOIN student ON student.student_id=course_student.student_id  
 GROUP BY course.course_name
 ORDER BY course.course_name
```

This second one is going to fail in your large courses because of a limitation of `GROUP_CONCAT()`. You may need to write application code to organize your web page course by course, or student by student.

Comment: i still get duplicate data , i need those emails to belong to a specific course as the student is registered only for that course.So Course A should contain all the students that belong to CourseA ect. here is a pic tinypic.com/r/kbxi78/8

Comment: my answer stands updated. If this doesn't do it for you, you'll need to provide some sample input data and desired output data.

Comment: its for my class and i have been trying to figure this out for hours. i just dont want duplicate radio buttons and within those radio buttons needs to be the students email for which course the student is registered for, so later the student can be email based on course